# How do I build report projects using Visual Studio 2012 on the command line?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution with several ".rptproj" projects that build fine when I am running the IDE, but when I try to run `devenv` on the command line I get the following error for each report project:

> Error: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

A quick search reveals several people are having the same problem but there are no solutions yet. I have Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012 installed, which is how we are able to build from the IDE.

Note: there is a [Microsoft Connect ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/781872/fail-to-build-ssis-ssas-projects-via-vs2012-command-line-devenv-exe-with-ssdt-bi-tool-installed#tabs) for  this problem.

Comment: The workaround you posted in the Connect ticket is nasty. You should at least post it here and get some rep. And it'll actually be Google-able ;)

Comment: Mostly why I didn't want to post it here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround that I came up with out of necessity to move on.  It's not very nice but it allowed me to get what I needed in CI.

> To work around this issue I excluded all of my report projects from my normal Solution Configurations and added a new ReportOnly configuration that only builds the report projects. Then on my CI server I build the non-Report configurations against Visual Studio 2012 and the ReportOnly configuration against Visual Studio 2010.

Up to date conversation and additional workarounds (if discovered) can be found in the [Microsoft Connect ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/781872/fail-to-build-ssis-ssas-projects-via-vs2012-command-line-devenv-exe-with-ssdt-bi-tool-installed#tabs).